# Pull all IIS Websites and WebApps and parse out each web.config file to show details of SQL Connection

Tags: powershell, iis

We need to get an inventory of each website and the websites web applications database used along with what server the database is on. This can get pulled from web config file. We will also pull details about the server. We will run this on each server and then join the csv output to pull together the full list.  Some of the websites and webapps use UNC paths to the web.config on a DFS and some are local on the server, so to avoid credentials issue we run script locally on each server.

I have a script, but it doesn't pull the root Sites web.config information, only its Web Applications, and only the first web application in each Site, so if I have 5 web apps on a site, it only pulls info on the first web application and skips the other 4 web applications. I can't seem to get it to loop through each web application for each IIS Site. I also need to pull the IIS Sites own web.config info, lack of a better word the *root* of the website.

Reason for this is to pull together an inventory of all our servers, what web apps are running on them, and what SQL Servers, SQL Databases and user id used to connect for everything.

```
Function Get-WebApplicationReport {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName
    )
        Begin {
        }
        Process {
            $ComputerName | ForEach-Object {
                $Server = $_
                $icArgs = @{}
                If ($Server -and ($Server -ne $ENV:ComputerName)) {$icArgs['ComputerName'] = $Server}
                Invoke-Command @icArgs -ScriptBlock {

                    Import-Module WebAdministration

                    Get-Website |
                        ForEach-Object {


                    $Time = Get-Date
                    #! This does a RegEx, if the connection string uses something thats not searched for in RegEx it will miss it.
                    #! make sure all possible entries for a field is in the RegEx!
                    $dbRegex = "((Initial\sCatalog)|((AttachDBFilename))|(database))\s*=\s*'?(?<ic>.+?)('|;|\Z)"
                    $dbsrvrRegex="((Data\sSource)|((server)))\s*=\s*'?(?<ic>.+?)('|;|\Z)"
                    $ipRegEx = "(((IPV4Address)))\s*=\s*'?(?<ic>.+?)('|;|}|\Z)"
                    $UserIDRegex="((User\sId)|((uid)))\s*=\s*'?(?<ic>.+?)('|;|\Z)"

                    Get-webapplication -Site $_.Name | ForEach-Object {
                        $webApp = $_
                        $(

                            If ([System.IO.File]::Exists("$($webApp.PhysicalPath)\Web.config")) {
                                $webConfig = [xml](Get-Content "$($webApp.PhysicalPath)\Web.config")
                                ForEach ($connString In $webConfig.configuration.connectionStrings.add) {
                                    [PsCustomObject][ordered]@{
                                        'web.config File' =  'YES'
                                        'Connection Name' =  $connString.name
                                        'Connection String' = $connString.connectionString
                                        'Database' =   $(If ($connString.connectionString -match $dbRegex) {$Matches['ic']} Else {'<UNKNOWN>'})
                                        'DB_Server' =    $(If ($connString.connectionString -match $dbsrvrRegex) {$Matches['ic']} Else {'<UNKNOWN>'})
                                        'User_ID' =             $(If ($connString.connectionString -match $UserIDRegex) {$Matches['ic']} Else {'<UNKNOWN>'})

                                    }
                                }
                                If (-not $connString) {
                                    [PsCustomObject][ordered]@{
                                        'web.config File' =  'YES'
                                        'Connection Name' =  $null
                                        'Connection String' = $null
                                        'Database' =   $null
                                    }
                                }
                            } Else {
                                [PsCustomObject][ordered]@{'web.config File' = 'NO'}

                            }

                        ) | Select-Object -Property `
                                @{n='Time-UTC';    e={$Time.ToUniversalTime()}},
                                @{n='ComputerName';   e={$ENV:ComputerName}},
                                @{n='OS Name';             e={ (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption}},
                                @{n='OS Version';          e={ (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).Version}},
                                @{n='IIS Version';          e={ [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("$env:SystemRoot\system32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe").ProductVersion}},
                                @{n='IP';                   e={If ((Test-Connection $env:COMPUTERNAME -Count 1 | Select-Object IPV4Address) -match $ipRegEx) {$Matches['ic']} Else {'<UNKNOWN>'}}},
                                @{n='Web Application';  e={$webApp.Path}},
                                @{n='Site Name';   e={If ($webApp.ItemXPath -match "@name\s*=\s*'(?<Name>.*?)'") {$Matches['Name']} Else {'<UNKNOWN>'}}},
                                @{n='Physical Path';  e={$webApp.PhysicalPath}},
                                @{n='Application Pool';  e={$webApp.ApplicationPool}},
                                'web.config File',
                                'Connection Name',
                                'Connection String',
                                'Database',
                                'DB_Server',
                                'User_ID'
                    } 
                  } 
                } 
            } 
        }
        End {
        }
    }

 #Get Computers Hostname   
$Hostname = get-content env:computername
#File path to save local csv file
$filePath = "c:\"
#Timestamp to use in File Name
$timestamp = get-date -format yyyyMMddHHmmss
# Creation of file name
$fileName =  $Hostname + "_"+"IIS_Details_"+[string]$timestamp + ".csv"
#Merging File Path and File name
$filePathfull = Join-Path $filePath $fileName



    $Report = Get-WebApplicationReport
    $Report | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $filePathfull
    #Comment Gridview line below , only used for testing.
    $Report | Out-GridView
```

Comment: PowerShell can be debugged https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/debugging-powershell-script-in-visual-studio-code-part-1/ So you'd better help yourself first.

Comment: Thanks Lex for the article. Its something i need to learn. However, Debuging does have a learning curve on how to use it properly.  I have tried using it following the website you sent and the second part of the article. I can see that the get-website and get-webapplication are passing the site info and application info. But it seems to skip some, for reason I cannot figure out.  It should grab them all, it would just not parse out configuration string if there wasnt one.  I will keep playing around with Debug.  Thanks again.